Which algorithm for meta model in SuperLearner?
Which algorithm do you use as the meta-model for a SuperLearner? I always see regression commonly, but I'm not getting good predictions with it. I tried all the other algorithms in my SuperLearner and got increasingly better prediction performance until I ran Random Forest, which got me ROC AUC = 1. Most likely, that is overfitting. How do I know if any other algorithms might be overfitting, and how do I justify their use if RF is overfitting?
